# Urn Problem with replacement on extraction

Tags: probability

Consider an urn with two type of balls white and black with proportionality $p,q$ respectively such that $p+q=1$ we extract balls $n$-time successively with replacement. Whats the probability that a white ball will appear for the first time in the n-extractions?im confused on how does extracting with replacement affect the calculations.

So let $W$ : the event to extract a white ball ,
and  $B$ : the event to extract a black ball
so they are asking to find the $P(W_n) = P(B) \cdot ... \cdot P(B) \cdot P(W) \iff P(W_n) = {(1-p)}^{n-1} \cdot p$ correct? is this some geometrical distribution?
For anyone confused on this question here is an example : suppose you extracted 5 balls (with replacement idk what that means) you got 4 black balls, and the fifth is the only white one, whats the probability that we got white on the fifth extraction?

Comment: You should have p and q in factors, not their reciprocals.

Comment: If it makes it easier to think about, imagine a (possibly biased) coin with one side white and the other black.

Comment: Note:  I don't understand the question.  What does "the probability that a white ball will appear for the first time in the $n$ extractions" mean?  It sounds like you just mean "at least one of the $n$ draws is white."  Is that it?  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: $q^{n-1}\cdot p$ would be the probability that the first white ball to appear would be on the $n$th extraction.  $1-q^n$ would be the probability that the  first white ball to appear would be in one of the first $n$ extractions.

Comment: @lulu suppose you extracted 5 balls (with replacement idk what that means) you got 4 black balls, and the fifth is the only white one

Comment: Your post doesn't say anything like that.  Are you sure that's what you intended? If so, please edit your post to reflect that.
 But if that's what you meant to write, then your answer is correct except that you should have $q,p$ instead of their reciprocals.

Comment: @Henry so the probability of extracting exactly k white balls in the first n extractions is $p^k \cdot q^{n-k}$?

Comment: @Henry also the probability of the k-th white ball to appear at the n-th extraction is : $p^{k-1} \cdot q^{n-k-1} \cdot p^n$?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI No - exactly $k$ white balls in the first $n$ extractions would be the binomial ${n \choose k}p^k \cdot q^{n-k}$

Comment: @Henry i think you forgot we have extractions by replacements so the order of how the k white balls appear isnt really important?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI I did not forget - without replacement (and a finite number of balls), you move from binomial to hypergeometric

Comment: Ah i understand now you are correct @Henry

Comment: @trueblueanil it doesnt change the fact that Henry's answer is valid

Comment: @trueblueanil - yes, all my comments assume *with* replacement (i.e. $p$ and $q$ do not change based on earlier draws)